# Can you change priority between wordform and lemmatizer in Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx, stemming

If I turn lemmatizer on then plurals all work e.g

```
Office=Offices
Dog=Dogs
```

However if I make a wordform unrelated to plural like

```
100 > Hundred
```

Then Hundred will not match Hundreds (I realize not a perfect example so don't take it literally).

So the question is is there any other type of wordform or process that will allow you to first apply stemming and then wordform? So in this case it would stem Hundred to Hundreds so that 100 would match both Hundred and Hundreds?

Answer (score 0):

See http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-wordforms

There is special syntax to use with morphology.

```
100 => Hundr
```

**You need to apply the morphology to the right side manually.**

Some code here: 
http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=13907
that might help with creating this style of wordforms.